# Display image that depends on user input

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm planning on creating a program that will have a login form and then a profile for each user. I'll be putting a `picturebox` that will display the image of the user.

My problem is how to put a variable in the Image.FromFile(); parameter.

The image will come from a local folder, btw.

Here's what I would like to do:

1. user logs in (ie. user name is stackoverflow)
2. on the profile window, an image named stackoverflow.jpg should be displayed.

Is there a way I can do that?

Image.FromFile("c:\filename.jpg"); <--- change the parameter with a variable that will depend on the username of the user.

Comment: Do you know the concatenation operator, `+`?

Comment: Yes. Thank you for reminding me :D Pardon my stupidity. Still a newbie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just have each file saved as the username:

```
Image.FromFile(imageDirectory + username + ".jpg");
```

would then return the file associated with that user. `imageDiretory` can be set as a variable so you dont have to change it everywhere in the code if the directory changes where you store the files, and then the username can be determined when the user logs in.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The images will be named with the username of the user. I will try that suggestion. Thank you, sir.